# Meaning of the phrase 'absent causes'

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

While listening to a lecture I heard this "history as an absent cause". can anyone help me in understanding the meaning.

Comment: Could you add some context to the question?  What was the lecture about?

Comment: This is really a question better asked on a Philosophy site. We can tell you what the words mean literally, but interpreting the paradox would be off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because interpreting or discussing the paradox is better done on a site devoted to philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to [LINK](http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100538764)

> defined as an absent cause because it is nowhere present in and of
>   itself as an actual element.

This is confusing and theoretical and for me, almost impossible to explain to an non-English speaker who like me,  might be mostly unfamiliar with Spinoza.

I'd say "history as an absent cause" means there was no prior experience of this event, no history to draw upon. Why the speaker would use that expression is hard/impossible to say, and it is out of context without the entire paragraph or speech.